# Cut points, continuous paths and increasing sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

currently I have a question about the following point-set topology problem. Everything takes place in $(\mathbb C,|\cdot|)$ and we are given the following setup.

1. One has a sequence of closed connected sets of points in the complex plane $\{L_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ (the precise definition for this problem should be irrelavant) such that $L_t \subseteq L_{t+s}$ for each $s > 0$. So basically as $t$ increases the set grows aswell.
2. There exist continuous curves $\gamma$ such that for each $t \geq 0$ one has $\gamma : [-t,t] \to \mathbb C$ such that $\gamma([-t,t]) \subseteq L_t$. Moreover we know especially that $\gamma(t+s)$ and $\gamma(-(t+s))$ are not in $L_t$ and together with another given property one can actually proof that $\gamma(t)$ and $\gamma(-t)$ are cut points of $L_{t+s}$ for $s > 0$. Using the definition found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_point) this tells us (for example) that $L_{t+s} \setminus \gamma(t)$ is disconnected.

**Question**: We already have for each $t \geq 0 : \gamma([-t,t]) \subseteq L_t$ I want to proof that one actually has equality, i.e. $L_t = \gamma([-t,t])$.

**Idea**: Take for example $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb R$ then every point $c \in (a,b)$ is a cutpoint, the important take away here is that the ''end-points'' of the interval $[a,b]$ are not cutpoints. Here something similiar should be possible. Since $\gamma(t)$ is a cut point of $L_{t+s}$ it cannot be that that $L_{t+s} \setminus L_t$ did not grow ''along'' $\gamma(t)$. Growing say along the middle of the curve around $\gamma(t/2)$ should contradict some combination of the notion of cut point and continuity of $\gamma$ but I find it hard to write down precisely.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't true in general. Take $L_t$ to be the closed disk of radius $t$ centered at $0$, and let $\gamma$ be the line segment between $-t$ and $t$ on the real axis (i.e., the diameter of $L_t$ on the real axis.

So if you have particular sets $L_t$ in mind, you may need to tell us what they are.

Comment: @MPW I might add some more details soon but I don't understand your comment, since if you take the closed disks $\overline{B}(0,t)$ for the sets $L_t$ then $L_{t+s} - \gamma(t)$ is still connected (it is still path conected and hence connected), $\gamma(t)$ is not a cut-point for $\overline{B}(0,s+t)$ and thus this not valid counterexample?

Comment: I totally misread your setup (2). I was thinking of removing the entire curve $\gamma$, not just the point $\gamma(t)$. So ignore the previous comment completely :(

Comment: No worries, I still believe you got a valid point take for example $L_t = B(0,t)$ and a curve $\gamma(t) = t$ if then $L_t$ grows a ''figure-eight'' shape on both sides then while containing the curve, then this seems to be valid counterexample. Do you need a picture?